# Pass errors through sessionStorage variable on HTML form reload

Tags: javascript, php, session

I am currently working with a form which takes user data and passes to to mySQL  on submission. It has an opening paragraph which I want to change on failed submission to display whatever errors apply. I want to pass my errors to the refreshed form on failure to show the user what went wrong.  Here is my Opening div.

```
<div id="formExplained">
     <h1>Title Here</h1>
     <p>Content Here</p>
</div>
```

On submission my script sets my $error variable to false, so form submission will can proceed when `$errors == false`. I checks for various errors in php and appends them one by one to $errors. At the end I

```
if($_POST['submit']){
  //variable to hold relavent error messages.  Set to false
          $error = false;
  //check each form field for errors
        if(!$title){
          $error .= $missingTitle;
        }else{
          $title = filter_var($title, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
          $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $title);
        }//Check for Grocoordinates
        if(!$lat || !$lng){
          $error .= $missingGeo;
        }//etc
```

Before I set up my mySQL query I do a check for errors and kill my code if they are present. Here I also pass my errors into `sessionStorage`, and echo a div containing my errors.

```
if($error){
          //pass errors from php to session Storage to display on reload
          echo "<script>sessionStorage.setItem('error', '$error');</script>";
          echo "<div id='error' class='error'>$error;</div>";
          echo "<p>Here Is Proof that this is Executing</p>";
          die();
        }
```

The div containing errors and the paragraph both execute perfectly on page reload. They are displayed at the bottom of my map.

In a seperate piece of javascript which I run above all the php submission code, I pull the sessionStorage variable and attempt to change my innerHTML from my opening div to reflect the errors.

```
<script>
  var error = sessionStorage.getItem('error');
    if(error){
        document.getElementById('formExplained').innerHTML = "<div class='error'><p>" + error + "</p></div>";
        }
</script>
```

This code will not execute correctly on my first submission, however on a second submission my errors are displayed at the top of my form as I desire. It seems that whatever I change as far as errors go, are displayed only after a delay of 2 refreshes.

Check out the page Im working with (http://www.sumoftruth.com/map/map.php).  The form is under "Offer Shelter"

Any guidance to get me out of this quagmire will be appreciated.

Comment: You should do the sessionstorage checking at the end of your file instead of the beginning

Comment: `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
(anonymous) @ map.php:52`

Comment: Thanks Shahaf! that was indeed the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this question.

As suggested by Shahaf,  I needed to move my session storage checking to the end of my script.

```
  if($error){
      //pass errors from php to session Storage to display on reload
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>sessionStorage.setItem('error', '$error');</script>";
        //Here is a script to pass the sessionStorage error variable to javascript variable
          echo "<script>";
          echo   "var error = sessionStorage.getItem('error');";
        //if any errors stored in sessionStorage, place them in main div
          echo  "if(error){";
        //write the error message into the main div in offerShelterForm
          echo    "document.getElementById('formExplained').innerHTML = \"<div class='error'><p>\" + error + \"</p></div>\";";
          echo  "}";
          echo "</script>";
        //kill the rest of the php code
          die();
        }
```